# How to set production environment for laravel applications.?

Tags: php, deployment, laravel, production

I have made a small application in laravel framework. bUT I want to host this app to my machine but in production environment so that nobody sees the errors page thrown by laravel framework. Please Note that I am not hosting it to any domain. It will be hosted on my system and will be accessed by others users locally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

edit the file app/config/app.php and set `'debug' => false`